# ASMB8-IKVM firmware update

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, ipmi, firmware, asus

I'm trying update firmware that there is 1.08 to more recent, I look in site official but not gotch result, all versions are defined with "unsuccessful" in verifying the firmware image
anyone can help me?

I tryed
https://www.asus.com/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/Z10PAD8/HelpDesk_BIOS/
https://drivers.eu/Server%20Products/ASUS/ASMB8-iKVM

Comment: I have the same problem I suggest contacting ASUS server support (EU email : ACG_TSD_SERVER@asus.com)